# Moving files to multiple destination

Tags: python, readfile, writefile

I am trying to move files in path folder to multiple destination directory. So my condition is 70 percent of files to move to dest1 and 30 percent to dest2. What i tried so far gives me some error. I am not sure if the logic is wrong or how to do this. Please post your solution or ideas. 
Thanks

Code:

```
import os
import shutil
import random
from shutil import copyfile
path="/Users/kj/Downloads/spam_classifier-master2/data2/data"
dest1="/Users/kj/Downloads/test"
dest2="/Users/kj/Downloads/train"


files=os.listdir(path)
for f in files:
    if (len(f) >0.7 ):
        shutil.move(f,dest2)
    elif (len(f)<0.3):
        shutil.move(f,dest1)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 544, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mail0.txt' -> '/Users/kj/Downloads/train'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kj/Downloads/ef.py", line 13, in <module>
    shutil.move(f,dest2)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 558, in move
    copy_function(src, real_dst)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 257, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 120, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mail0.txt'
```

Comment: how `len(something)` (should return `int`) can be less than `0.3` except being `0`?

Comment: Does the file 'mail0.txt' actually exist in path?

Comment: yes its one of the file in my path folder

Comment: Comparing `len(f) >0.7` is comparing the length of the filename in characters and which will always be a whole number, to `0.7`. The only time it wouldn't be true was if the filename was an empty string—which is very unlikely.

Comment: oh ok. I understand and is there any other way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.listdir` returns just the file names under given path, so when you perform an action on the file name, you should join the file name with the path to obtain the full path first. Also you should divide the file number by the length of the file list to obtain a proper ratio:

```
files=os.listdir(path)
for i, f in enumerate(files):
    if (i + 1) / len(files) > 0.7:
        shutil.move(os.path.join(path, f),dest2)
    else:
        shutil.move(os.path.join(path, f),dest1)
```

Comment: what is this th? and this program gives me invalid syntax

Comment: Accidentally hit submit when I was half-way editing it. Please try again.

Comment: i get a unix exec file why? also if i create test and train folder its giving me the folder already exists so without it, i get unix exec. Can i get the files into the folders?

Comment: My bad. Meant to type `len(files)` but typed `len(f)`. Fixed.